# Logical bug while inserting node at particular location

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Please consider my code below for inserting a node at a particular location assuming that the linkedlist is sorted:

```
package datastructures;
public class Link {
    int data;
    Link next;

    public Link(int d){
        this.data = d;
    }

    public void displayLink(){
        System.out.println(data + " ");
    }
   
    public static class LinkList {
        Link first;

        public void insertFirst(int x) {
            Link newLink = new Link(x);
            newLink.next = first;
            first = newLink;
        }

        public Link deleteFirst() {
            Link temp = first;
            first = first.next;
            return temp;
        }

        public void displayList() {
            Link current = first;
            while (current != null) {
               current.displayLink();
               current = current.next;
            }
        }
                            
        public void insertNodeAtParticularLocation(int x){
            Link previous = first;
            Link current = first.next;

            if (first == null){
                // if node doesn't exist in the 
                // linkedlist then just create a new node
                Link newNode = new Link(x);
            } else if (x < first.data) {
                // Else if the value that needs to be inserted
                // is less than the first element, then insert 
                // it at the very beginning
                      
                Link newNode = new Link(x);
                newNode.next = first;
                first = newNode;
            } else {
                while(current.data > x){ // In case of21,22,23,27 ; If x = 24 , current should stop at 27
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.next;
                    Link newNode = new Link(x);
                    previous.next = newNode;
                    newNode.next = current;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        LinkList addElements = new LinkList();
        
        addElements.insertFirst(21);
        addElements.insertFirst(22);
        addElements.insertFirst(23);
        addElements.insertFirst(27);
        addElements.insertFirst(29);
        
        System.out.println("Display Original Elements");
        
        addElements.displayList();
        
        addElements.insertNodeAtParticularLocation(24);
        
        System.out.println("Display Elements after First Modification");
        
        addElements.displayList();
    }
}
```

there is some problem with my `insertNodeAtParticularLocation()` method.

**Issue #1:**

When I tried to add `24`, it's still getting added to the end of the list and not at a specified location which should be after node with value `23`.

**Issue #2:**

Also, I tried adding another value `10` which I expected to be added at the beginning but it was overwriting the last element which was 27 and geting added over it's place. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I can't quite follow this. You shouldn't have `Link current = first.next;` followed by `if (first == null)`. If `first` was `null`, `first.next` would have thrown a `NullPointerException` the line before. Also, isn't the order of nodes `29, 27, 23, 22, 21` rather than `21, 22, 23, 27, 29` because you added `29` (at the beginning) last?

Comment: You are right for the first point. I should not have `Link current = first.next;` thing over there. Yes, the order of the nodes are `29, 27, 23, 22, 21`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

`insertFirst` pushes elements inserted earlier to the back. If you want to use insertFirst in main, you need to reverse the order:

```
addElements.insertFirst(29);
addElements.insertFirst(27);
addElements.insertFirst(23);
addElements.insertFirst(22);
addElements.insertFirst(21);
```

There are some issues with `insertNodeAtParticularLocation`:

- The first == null case doesn't work as it does not assign first
- The while loop looks like it may insert multiple elements in the wrong locations

I'd write `insertNodeAtParticularLocation` as follows:

```
    public void insertNodeAtParticularLocation(int x) {
        if (first == null || x < first.data) {
            // if the value that needs to be inserted
            // is less than the first element, or it does not exist,
            // then insert it at the very beginning
            insertFirst(x);
        } else {
            Link previous = first;
            Link current = first.next;
            while(current != null && current.data > x) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            Link newNode = new Link(x);
            previous.next = newNode;
            newNode.next = current;
        }
    }
```